# How to aggregate a different number of columns for each row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table which has data is below format:

[image]

Corresponding to an ID there is a year variable which represents the first time the reading reached a steady state (in the actual data its a month day combination), there will also be data for  time period before the stabilization period. The `a` columns represent a measure taken in that give year. I want to create a field which would sum only those fields relevant for a given id i.e. for Id=B I want to sum columns `a2015-a2019`. I want this to be done dynamically. But am not sure how to do it without using case when statements since the actual data is even more granular.

I intially tried to pivot the table at id, year and value level so i can first find the steady state time period for each id and simply sum/aggregate only those value post that but transpose feature is not available in standard-sql.

Comment: In your sample data, you can just sum all the columns.  I don't understand what the challenge is.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Edited the question with why i couldn't just sum all the columns

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I tried to transpose and then aggregate which seemed like the simpler option but i couldn't transpose the data.

Comment: can you share your table schema in text format, and expected output.

Comment: If the non-relevant fields are blank, wouldn't sum just ignore those fields? I don't think I fully understand why summing a2013 to a2019 for all id's wouldn't work, the nulls will just be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and quite generic to hopefully address your requirement (*"how to do it without using case when statements since the actual data is even more granular."*)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT t.*, 
  (
    SELECT SUM(CAST(SPLIT(kv, '":')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS INT64))
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"a(\d{4}":\d*)')) kv
    WHERE CAST(SPLIT(kv, '":')[OFFSET(0)] AS INT64) >= year
  ) total,
  ARRAY (
    SELECT AS STRUCT SPLIT(kv, '":')[OFFSET(0)] AS key, SPLIT(kv, '":')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS value
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"a(\d{4}":\d*)')) kv
    WHERE CAST(SPLIT(kv, '":')[OFFSET(0)] AS INT64) >= year
  ) details
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

if to apply to sample data from your question  - result is

```
Row id  year    a2013   a2014   a2015   a2016   a2017   a2018   a2019   total   details.key details.value    
1   a   2014    0       342     2432    34234   645     123     65      37841   2014        342  
                                                                                2015        2432     
                                                                                2016        34234    
                                                                                2017        645  
                                                                                2018        123  
                                                                                2019        65   
2   b   2015    0       0       54      234     34      5656    3       5981    2015        54   
                                                                                2016        234  
                                                                                2017        34   
                                                                                2018        5656     
                                                                                2019        3    
3   c   2016    0       0       0       765     34654   2345    654     38418   2016        765  
                                                                                2017        34654    
                                                                                2018        2345     
                                                                                2019        654
```

As you can see  - I included here extra column `Details` so you can see which exactly entries are getting summed - this is just for troubleshooting. you can remove this from the query as it is not really needed

Answer (score 1):

Following is a standard logic for your purpose. Syntax may different for BigQuery, but you can adjust accordingly and use the given logic below-

```
SELECT A.id,A.year,SUM(A.Val)
FROM
(
    SELECT id,year,[a2013] Val,2013 Yr FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,year,[a2014],2014 FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,year,[a2015],2015 FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,year,[a2016],2016 FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,year,[a2017],2017 FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,year,[a2018],2018 FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,year,[a2019],2019 FROM your_table
)A
WHERE A.year <= A.Yr
GROUP BY A.id,A.year
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using this.

```
select Id, year, (isnull(a2013,0) + isnull(a2014,0) + isnull(a2015,0) + isnull(a2016,0) 
                + isnull(a2017,0) + isnull(a2018,0) + isnull(a2019,0) ) as Total
from table
```